# Windows 8 apps not working

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-apps

I have an Acer laptop with genuine Window 8. My Windows 8 apps are not working. When I open any app, the app does not respond. I am not able to open my webcam too.

Comment: You might find this problem is fixed by installing the Windows 8.1 update.

Comment: is there any other solution instead of installing Windows 8.1 upgrade?

Comment: You can try creating a new user profile to verify the problem only exists in the current user profile.